# How to get data from ManaToManyField from forms into Django Views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):
   """model for CreatePost"""
   author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

   blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

   sub_catagory = models.ManyToManyField('SubCatagory')

   post_cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_cover_images', null=False, blank=False)

   post_discription = HTMLField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Enter the detailed post in max. 5000 characters')

   date_published = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)

class Catagory(models.Model):
   """model for Catagory"""
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter a ctagory for blogpost')

class SubCatagory(models.Model):
   """model for subcatagories"""
   catagory = models.ForeignKey('Catagory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   sub_catagory_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter subcatagory')
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ('blog_title', 'sub_catagory', 'post_cover_image', 'post_discription')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def createpost(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        PostForm = PostCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if PostForm.is_valid():

            postcont = Posts()

            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                postcont.blog_title = PostForm.cleaned_data['blog_title']
                postcont.post_cover_image = PostForm.cleaned_data['post_cover_image']
                postcont.post_discription = PostForm.cleaned_data['post_discription']
                postcont.author = request.user.username
                postcont.sub_catagory = PostForm.cleaned_data['sub_catagory']
                postcont.date_published = datetime.date.today()
                postcont.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('postcreationsuccessful'))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('createpost'))

    else:
        PostForm = PostCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'createpost.html', {'PostForm':PostForm})
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block title %}<title>Create Post</title>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'createpost' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        {% load bootstrap %}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            {{ PostForm.blog_title|bootstrap }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            {{ PostForm.post_cover_image|bootstrap }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            {{ PostForm.sub_catagory|bootstrap }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            {{ PostForm.post_discription }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Post">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

My question that I have a manytomany relationship in Posts and SubCatagory. As a subcatagory can have many posts. I want to get the catagories chosen by the user and want to save them in models using views.py function.

I want to ask how I can do that. When I try to do this:

postcont.sub_catagory = PostForm.cleaned_data['sub_catagory']

I get the following error:

TypeError at /posts/createpost/
  Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use sub_catagory.set() instead.

Anyone please help!

Comment: Hold on, you construct an instance yourself based on the form? Why? You can use the `PostForm.save()` after the `is_valid`, furthermore better use variables with lowercase, so `post_form`.

Comment: I will not be able to save date_published and username to the models if I use PostForm.save() statement.

Comment: you can, by simply first constructing an object, and then passing it with `instance=my_object` in the `Form`.

Comment: Furthermore you can make `date_published` an `DateField(auto_add_now=True)` such that it will automatically set the date to the one where the instance was constructed.

Comment: I try it. Is it useful for saving manytomanyfield choices?

Answer (score 1):

Well like the error says,t he problem is with this line:

```
postcont.sub_catagory = PostForm.cleaned_data['sub_catagory']
```

`sub_category` is a `ManyToManyField`, so you can not set this to an object directly. You can use `postcont.sub_category.set(PostForm.cleaned_data['sub_category'])`, but this is still not very elegant.

Your view does not really have to do patch all the fields to the object. We can let the form do the work:

```
@login_required
def createpost(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        post_form = PostCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.instance.auther = request.user.username
            postcont.instance.date_published = datetime.date.today()
            post_form.save()
            return redirect('postcreationsuccessful')
    else:
        post_form = PostCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'createpost.html', {'PostForm': post_form})
```

Some extra remarks:

1. the `if request.user.is_authenticated` is useless since the `@login_required` decorator already checks this;
2. if the `author` is a `User`, it is better to use a `ForeignKey(User, ...)` here;
3. you can use `date_published = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True, null=False)` for the `date_published` field, to make sure that the `date_published is automatically set to the date when the object was constructed;
4. by not redirecting in case the form is invalid, you can actually render the form with the errors, such that the user can fix the form, and resubmit again; and
5. you can use a `return redirect(..)` which is a shortcut of a `reverse(..)` wrapped in a `HttpResponseRedirect(..)` object.